# "Child of" bone constraint moving the child to the parent

Tags: rigging

I'm following a tutorial and we are using IK (Inverse Kinematics) the person says to add a "Child of" constraint to one of the bones, but when I do this it moves it to where the parent is, but the tutorial video doesn't get that it just stays the same.

Here is without the constraint:

[image: Without the constraint]

Here is it with the constraint:

[image: With the constraint]

I have no clue why this is happening, can someone please help me?

Comment: Enter pose mode, select the bone with the constraint, and hit the "set inverse" button.  It should jump back to where it was a second ago.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you so much! I really wanted to finish this tutorial and this helped!

Comment: I'll do it when i get to school :)